# Formatting Pandas datetime in Bokeh HoverTool

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I am trying to get the tooltip to have a nicely formatted datetime value which is to microsecond precision. With the following code I always get a measurement that is in `TB%` which is obviously incorrect. I would like the "Date" in the tooltip to display in the same format as in the "date_time" field in the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.models import HoverTool
from bokeh.models.formatters import DatetimeTickFormatter
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_notebook, show


output_notebook()

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400, x_axis_type="datetime")


d = {
    'timestamp_micros': [1530479286336096,1530479286362156,1530479286472230,1530479286488213,1530479286495292], 
    'height': [6, 7, 2, 4, 5],
    'info': ['foo','bar','baz','qux','quux'],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp_micros'], unit='us')
display(df)


p.circle(x='date_time', y='height', source=df, line_width=2, size=15, color="navy", alpha=0.5)
p.line(x='date_time', y='height', source=df, line_width=2, color="navy", alpha=0.5)

hover = HoverTool(
    tooltips = [
        ("Date", "@date_time{%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f}"),
        ("Value", "@height{0.000000}"),
        ("info", "@info"),
    ],
    formatters={
        'Date': 'datetime',
        'Value' : 'printf',
    },    
)
p.add_tools(hover)

p.xaxis.formatter=DatetimeTickFormatter(
    microseconds = ['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'],
    milliseconds = ['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%3N'],
    seconds = ["%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"],
    minsec = ["%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"],
    minutes = ["%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"],
    hourmin = ["%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"],
    hours=["%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"],
    days=["%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"],
    months=["%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"],
    years=["%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"],
)
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = math.pi/2

show(p)
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your formatters specification is wrong, in a couple of ways:

- The `formatters` dict maps *column names* to formats, you have the tooltip labels as keys
- The value of the printf format is not given correctly, it should be `%0.00000f` e.g.
- There is no `%f` datetime format that I am aware of, maybe you mean `%3N`?

With these changes:

```
hover = HoverTool(
    tooltips = [
        ("Date", "@date_time{%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%3N}"),
        ("Value", "@height{%0.000000f}"),
        ("info", "@info"),
    ],
    formatters={
        'date_time': 'datetime',
        'height' : 'printf',
    },
)
```

You get:

[image]

If you need something more specialized, there is also the [`CustomJSHover`](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/tools.html#bokeh.models.tools.CustomJSHover) in Bokeh >= 0.13 which allows you to completely control the formatting arbitrarily by providing a snippet of JavaScript to do the whatever you need.

Comment: If you want `%f` as described in [the doc](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/formatters.html#bokeh.models.formatters.DatetimeTickFormatter), you should use `%6N`.

Answer (score 7):

If your DataColumn is of the format "@something", you must also specify that in the formatter. Otherwise the format will not match and most probably interpret your format string as percentage. Thus, the above example should be:

```
hover = HoverTool(
   tooltips = [
       ("Date", "@date_time{%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%3N}"),
       ("Value", "@height{%0.000000f}"),
       ("info", "@info"),
   ],
   formatters={
       '@date_time': 'datetime',
       '@height' : 'printf',
   },
)
```

Comment: This answer works in bokeh 2.2.3. The answer above lacks the "@" prefix under `formatters`.